# Poor performance in FVWM - Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: compiz, performance

I've installed Ubuntu desktop on my Lenovo T450 laptop, and then installed FVWM according to [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FVWM). When in FVWM, switching desktops to ones that have games or Chrome on them results in a momentary wait before the screen finally refreshes. If I log out and log into Unity, those same apps behave fine.

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this. It's using the same video driver for both, so if one was having issues, I'd expect the other to have issues as well. A few Google searches seem to point to Compiz, but the documentation doesn't mention it; in fact, it says that xcompmgr is preferred over xgl, and I'm not sure if there are other options to try.

Is there a way I can disable Compiz without switching to xgl? Or is there some other way I can tell what might be giving me issues?